# How can I generate a background gradient that will allow me to read all named colors?

Tags: css

I've been generating a random background gradient but sometimes the named color still matches the background gradient colors too much. Is there anyway to ensure any random named css color will be readable on a background?

```
<span style="
 color: ${getRandomColor()};
 background: linear-gradient(
 0deg,
 ${getRandomColor()} 0%,
 ${getRandomColor()} 100%);
">some text here</span>
```

My `getRandomColor()` function is this:

```
function getRandomColor() {
    const colors = getColors();

  return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}

function getColors() {
    return 'aliceblue antiquewhite aqua aquamarine azure beige bisque black blanchedalmond blue blueviolet brown burlywood cadetblue chartreuse chocolate coral cornflowerblue cornsilk crimson currentcolor cyan darkblue darkcyan darkgoldenrod darkgray darkgreen darkgrey darkkhaki darkmagenta darkolivegreen darkorange darkorchid darkred darksalmon darkseagreen darkslateblue darkslategray darkslategrey darkturquoise darkviolet deeppink deepskyblue dimgray dimgrey dodgerblue firebrick floralwhite forestgreen fuchsia gainsboro ghostwhite gold goldenrod gray green greenyellow grey honeydew hotpink indianred indigo ivory khaki lavender lavenderblush lawngreen lemonchiffon lightblue lightcoral lightcyan lightgoldenrodyellow lightgray lightgreen lightgrey lightpink lightsalmon lightseagreen lightskyblue lightslategray lightslategrey lightsteelblue lightyellow lime limegreen linen magenta maroon mediumaquamarine mediumblue mediumorchid mediumpurple mediumseagreen mediumslateblue mediumspringgreen mediumturquoise mediumvioletred midnightblue mintcream mistyrose moccasin navajowhite navy none oldlace olive olivedrab orange orangered orchid palegoldenrod palegreen paleturquoise palevioletred papayawhip peachpuff peru pink plum powderblue purple rebeccapurple red rosybrown royalblue saddlebrown salmon sandybrown seagreen seashell sienna silver skyblue slateblue slategray slategrey snow springgreen steelblue tan teal thistle tomato transparent turquoise violet wheat white whitesmoke yellow yellowgreen'.split(' ');
}
```

Comment: Your question is not quite clear, can you please explain, **what do you want to happen in webiste**

Comment: i want to take a random color and get a slighly darker color of it from a named color. the idea is the foreground is brighter than the background (say get 60% darker version of the named color)